# Why does firebase store access token in index DB for flutter web?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-web

I realized firebase auth for flutter web stores the user's access token in index DB. I thought this is not safe. I understand the access token must be persistent to maintain the authentication state. But based on the research I made [here](https://community.auth0.com/t/should-i-store-jwt-tokens-in-indexeddb/63100) and [here](https://dev.to/gkoniaris/how-to-securely-store-jwt-tokens-51cf), I understood storing access tokens in local storage, session storage, and index DB are all vulnerable to XSS attacks therefore httpOnly cookies should be used instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? What is your concern? Auth tokens need to be persisted somewhere in order to be reused between launches so the user doesn't have to sign in each time. Any location on disk private to the app will be just as secure as any other similarly permissioned location.

Comment: I understand the token must be persistent. But based on the research I made, I understood storing access tokens in local storage, session storage and index DB are all vulnerable to XSS attacks and httpOnly cookies should be used instead.

Comment: Maybe you would like to add the detailed results of your findings, including citations and links that people can review, into your question to better explain your concern.  What you have now is not really communicating very thoroughly.

Comment: sorry about that, here you go.
https://community.auth0.com/t/should-i-store-jwt-tokens-in-indexeddb/63100
https://dev.to/gkoniaris/how-to-securely-store-jwt-tokens-51cf

Comment: Please *edit the question* to fully explain your concerns.  Don't leave critical pieces of information in comments.  As your question stands now, it is at risk of closure for not being clear.

Comment: I'm not an expert in firebase authentication and JWT tokens. But did you consider that you might getting different token's to same account on different browser and system you work in ? I'm pretty sure it's not that simple to just get someone's token and be able to log in to his account.